# What defines a civilization as being advanced?

Tags: civilization

<s>Are there any hard rules or requirements that constitute a civilization as being considered advanced? Or is it merely by comparison to other (neighboring?) civilizations?</s>

Is a civilization considered "advanced" by comparing it to other civilizations or are there requirements that a civilization would need to meet to be considered "advanced"?

<s>Bonus question: When did the first human civilization become advanced?</s>

Comment: *When did the first human civilization become advanced?* Hasn't happened yet, IMO.  Science still denied by politicians and many religious groups.  Women still not equal in most of the world, even in terms of basic rights.  I could add to the list for a long time.

Comment: flagging this as opinion based, since its asking for an objective definition of a relative term

Comment: "Advanced" is obviously a relative term. I have no clue why anybody would even think that it is an absolute term.

Comment: @StephenG Using social circumstances as an advancement metric is terrible. Your comment leads me to think that you hold secular-rational values, but consider how your perfect society would seem to someone holding conservative-religious values. Definitly not advanced. This only gets worse if you are talking about aliens, as they might have different social structures based on things like their biologie.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight If you look at what I said, you're implying that conservative-religious types would consider denying science a *good* thing and denying women equal rights a *good* thing.  That's advanced civilization, is it ?  Happy to be labelled "secular-rational" if the alternative is what you're implying. :-)

Comment: I'd like some help with my Q. How is this opinion based? I was asking if there are rules to define it or if it's relative (and it was answered to be the latter). I've reworded it as best as possible to clarify this. @AlexP I wasn't sure if it was a relative term in this context as it's a phrase commonly heard. Think of advanced mathematics compared to math in school. Yes, one is more "advanced" than the other, but there are certain qualifications (topics) that Advanced Math would cover that Math wouldn't. That's what I was looking to see if it existed.

Comment: OK now I'm additionally confused after rewording my question. A civilization could be advanced compared to another one, BUT it could also be advanced when compared to a list of qualifications. Both cases could be considered as "relative" (relative to another civilization or relative to a list of requirements).

Comment: I've never heard of a subject called "Advanced Mathematics". I would appreciate a link to a higher education curriculum containing a course in "Advanced Mathematics" (as opposed to the usual Linear Algebra, Calculus, Statistics, Descriptive Geometry and so on).

Comment: Advanced Mathematics is a category. As is (Basic) Mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_mathematics_topics#Areas_of_advanced_mathematics

Comment: The categories "Basic" and "Advanced" in the WP article you linked are bogus. Note the complete lack of citations; also note that WP lacks articles for Basic or Advanced Mathematics. There does indeed exist a category of "[elementary mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_mathematics)", which is commonly held to contain those areas of mathematics taught in primary school and middle school (grades 1 to 8, that is, before high school). What *exactly* is contained in elementary mathematics varies *a lot* from historical period to historical period and from country to country.

Comment: Here's a link to a higher education curriculum containing a course in "Advanced Mathematics": Math 3325, Transition to Advanced Mathematics. This course is an introduction to proofs and the abstract approach that characterizes upper level mathematics courses. It serves as a transition into advanced mathematics... as they study any type of advanced mathematics, whether it be in pure mathematics, applied mathematics, or application-oriented courses... such as Real Analysis, Abstract Algebra, and Advanced Linear Algebra... https://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/MathClasses/MathClasses-List.html

Comment: Technically, this isn't a worldbuilding question.  It's a philosophical question trying to categorize technological, philosophical, sociological, and demographic conditions.  That's always opinion-based, but the question could just as easily be closed as not-about-worldbuilding.

Comment: How so? I'm trying to build a world and wanted to understand what my civilization needs to have to be considered "advanced". I'd like to specifically explore the time period in this world when this transition into becoming "advanced" occurs.

Comment: @StephenG My point is that everyone would consider a culture dedicated to their own values superior, thus advanced. A conservative-religious, secular-rational or authoritarian-technocratic type would each think that a society upholding and acting on their values to be "a good thing". Your point of view only works if moral is absolute and not relative. While there is quite the philosophical debate about this, absolute moral is generally common among religious types and relative moral is supported by more secular types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Advanced is a relative term.

Western society is advanced compared to a primitive hunter gatherer tribe but still primitive compared to a star faring alien race.

It assumes you're normal/baseline and then rates others as compared to you.

Answer (score 3):

**How About a Metric?**

The [Kardashev Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale) is a popular metric for technological advancement of civilizations.  The scale is based on energy use and has three levels:

Civilization can (and does) harness:

1. the total energy available on its planet
2. the total energy available from its star
3. the total energy available from its galaxy

There are plenty of issues one can take with this metric.  Probably the most apparent is that we have no idea what technological advancement looks like beyond our current state and thus energy usage may be a poor indicator.

If you put humans on the Kardashev scale they fall around a 0.7.  Note that this doesn't mean we harness 70% of the available energy on Earth, since the scale is logarithmic (we use around 0.001% of the available energy).

**So What is Advanced?**

Even the Kardashev scale doesn't really answer your question though.  To us, a type I civilization would seem very advanced.  To a type 0.1 civilization (proto-humans), we would seem very advanced.  Since type III is the highest measure, do we consider that "advanced?"  Some people propose even higher types (harnessing the power of an entire universe) so were these civilizations to exist type III would seem paltry in comparison.

**Wait...**

I got on a roll here because I like the subject, but your question doesn't have an answer because you are asking for a metric to define something that is inherently relative.  In fact, now I'm not sure I should have answered at all.